# Disable border in tag select during printing in Opera 38.0

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, printing, opera

please, help me set **border** over *CSS* for tag **select** for media **print** in Opera 38.0. I need disable print its border. This setting not function:

```
select{border:none !important;}
```

Thank

Jarda

Answer (score 0):

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #fff !important;
```

This worked for me :)